# Case statement for multiple variables

Tags: sql

So we have variety of products, including fruits and non-expired stuff such as paper. Product --------- Expiration How can I do case statement to show: case when product is not apple or product is not orange then fill the expiration 1?

Comment: Please provide us with some sample data and table structure, the expected result set, and the query you have grown so far so that other may help.

Comment: Case fully supports and/or logic.   case when this = true or (that is null and this = false) then 1 else 'I am a banana' end

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Union instead of a case statement .. (table structure and column structure non known, but you can use the concept below.

```
select productname, expiratieonDate as Expiration
  from <table>
 where productType = fruits
UNION
select productname, 1 as Expiration
  from <table>
 where productType = nonexpiration
```